# How to order by a segment of preg_match_all results?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm using PHP to generate a list of references to a text by doing a preg_match_all search on a database table. Here is the PHP code:

```
$query = "SELECT primary_tag,display_short_title,content FROM topics;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if (preg_match_all("/(\<i\>U\<\/i\>|U) [0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,7}/", $row["content"], $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $match = ltrim(strip_tags($match), "U ");
    echo '<p class="textmark_result">' . $match;
    echo '  <a href="../Essays/topic.php?shorttitle=' . $row["primary_tag"] . '">' . $row["display_short_title"] . '</a>';
    echo "</p>\n";
    }
  }
}
```

And the results (viewing source) look like this:

```
<p class="textmark_result">15.1737  <a href="../Essays/topic.php?shorttitle=medicine">Medicine</a></p>
<p class="textmark_result">5.678  <a href="../Essays/topic.php?shorttitle=science">Science</a></p>
<p class="textmark_result">14.665  <a href="../Essays/topic.php?shorttitle=science">Science</a></p>
```

In the resulting web page, I want to order the results by the decimal in the middle, the $match in the code, so that (in this example) 5.678 comes first, then 14.665, then 15.1737. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three steps to do:

1. Get all your matches and add them to an array - `floatval($match)` is the key.
2. Sort the resulting array by key (floats sort by numeric value, strings sort by characters  - therefore `floatval(...)`).
3. Iterate on the sorted array

Code:

```
// MySQL stuff goes here ...
// create empty array
$results = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (preg_match_all("/(\<i\>U\<\/i\>|U) [0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,7}/", $row["content"], $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
            $match = ltrim(strip_tags($match), "U ");
            // array pseudo key is the float value of $match
            // add '_key' member for usort()
            $row['_key'] = floatval($match);
            $results[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
// sort the array by the float key
usort($results, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['_key'] == $b['_key']) return 0;
    elseif($a['_key'] > $b['_key']) return 1;
    else return -1;
});

// ... then display stuff in order
foreach($results as $row) {
    echo '<p class="textmark_result">' . (string)$row['_key'];
    echo '  <a href="../Essays/topic.php?shorttitle=' 
    . $row["primary_tag"] . '">' . $row["display_short_title"] . '</a>';
    echo "</p>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight into floatval; I agree, that's crucial to the problem, and I didn't know about it. When I run your suggested code, it is stripping the decimal numbers down to integers and not reordering them. It produces 
'<p class="textmark_result">15  <a href="../Essays/topic.php?shorttitle=medicine">Medicine</a></p>
<p class="textmark_result">5  <a href="../Essays/topic.php?shorttitle=science">Science</a></p>
<p class="textmark_result">14  <a href="../Essays/topic.php?shorttitle=science">Science</a></p>' I'm starting to look at it now to see why that's happening.

Comment: I just looked this up and noticed that PHP doesn't support float indexes. I replaced `ksort()` with `usort()`. It now sorts the array by a "pseudo key" stored in the array value.

Comment: Thanks very much for checking on that. Your updated code restores the decimal values, but the results still aren't sorting. '<p class="textmark_result">15.1737  <a href="../Essays/topic.php?shorttitle=medicine">Medicine</a></p>
<p class="textmark_result">5.678  <a href="../Essays/topic.php?shorttitle=science">Science</a></p>
<p class="textmark_result">14.665  <a href="../Essays/topic.php?shorttitle=science">Science</a></p>' I'm checking on the sorting, too.

Comment: Ah yeah... of course. I wrote the sorting function in a test-scenario and forgot to change it. Changed the usort call to `usort($results, function($a, $b) { ... });`

Comment: Hmm. I see what you mean, but the new usort call produces the same result--everything perfect but the sorting. For whatever it's worth (and I'm a newbie, so this might be off point), I tried exploding and echoing the $results array just before the usort call to see what it's trying to sort, and nothing happens. Perhaps the array isn't getting made? I was just inserting '$results_ex = explode(", ", $results); echo $results_ex;'.

Comment: Well, try `var_dump($results)` instead of `explode()`. The array members are arrays themselves. When they are casted to strings (which is what `explode()` does), you won't get much from them. However, I tried this code with some dummy data and `var_dump($results)`ed before and after `usort(...)`, and it works fine for me.

Comment: Ah... I got it. The sorting and echoing has to be done outside the `for` loop, else the matches will only be sorted per fetched row. Made another update.